# how do i make visual studio quit re-formatting my xml?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

So, I'll be laying out an asp page, keeping my xml nice and neat and readable, and then something happens like I switch to a different window or something and then visual studio will reformat my xml into garbage. Is there anyway to stop it from doing this?!

It'll go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

And here are my settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XML should have you covered

Comment: ive had "Preserve manual attribute formatting" chosen from the Formatting sub-menu for a couple weeks now and it's still been doing it, just less often.

Comment: Make sure all the other tick boxes are unchecked in the formatting tab as well. It could also be cause by a plugin such as Resharper. If it is resharper, the settings are Resharper -> Options -> XML -> formatting Style

Comment: I had everything else unchecked, and I don't have resharper